# Access: Using query in VBA for recordset

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have been accustomed to do recordssets in the following format:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "Select field1, field2 from myTable where field1 > 30"

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

'... Do wahtever using rs.
```

Is it possible to use an already created query instead of text and giving it the where clause?

This is a linked table to a SQL Server 2008 Database. I like to save simple queries in Access.

Comment: Have a look at the first example where you can use Parameters in code http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff820966.aspx

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can either

- Use a query that has parameters and specify values for parameters provided that the query uses parameters.

  ```
  Dim dbs As DAO.Database
  Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
  Dim prm As DAO.Parameter
  Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

  Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qry_SomeQueryWithParameters")

  qdf.Parameters("SomeParam").Value = "whatever"

  Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset
  ```

or

- Specify a query name as the command and use the [Filter property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff837300.aspx) on the recordset

```
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rsFiltered As DAO.Recordset


    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(qry_SomeQueryWithoutParameters)

    rs.Filter = "field1 > 30"
    set rsFiltered  = rs.OpenRecordset
```

Comment: Using the second example had to add a statement to set another recordset initialized from the filterd recordset and use that, per the [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff837300.aspx) you provided. Thanks

Comment: @Rick nice. I've updated my answer to include the correction.

Comment: @ConradFrix I get "Syntaxfehler(fehlender Operator) in Abfrageausdruck 'massnahme=bankett'. My code: `abfrage = "SELECT * FROM tab1" ;Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(abfrage)

    rs.Filter = "15massnahme=bankett"
    
    rsf = rs.OpenRecordset`

Comment: @ConradFrix checking your first solution: I get "Error 3265, Element not found in this list" if I write `abfrage = "SELECT * FROM tab1"; Set qdf = db.QueryDefs(abfrage)`