# Tracking down an invalid procedure call error in a SQL VBA execute command

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Thanks for opening this. I've been wracking my brain for the past couple of days trying to make heads of tails of this error (Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call) error that has blocked me at every turn.

Essentially, my goal is to run and execute a SQL command to find the largest number in a given category and store it into a variable for later use. I've tried different ways to go about it and no matter how I do it (either in VBA using a DMAX or through SQL) I run into the same error whenever I try to execute the command. I've gotten some help working through it but I think there's some deeper issue that I am not understanding with VBA.

Here is the code:

```vb
Public Function GetMaxValue(Child As String)

    Dim RAC As DAO.RecordSet
    Dim Prefix As String
    Dim MaxVal As Long
    Dim SearchString As String

    NewPrefix = Child
    SearchString = "SELECT MAX([SalesValue]) FROM [SalesTable] WHERE [Prefix] = '" & NewPrefix & "';"

    Set RAC = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SearchString)

    If RAC.Fields.Count = 1 Then
          MaxVal = RAC.Fields(0)
    End If

    RAC.Close
    Set RAC = Nothing

End Function
```

It breaks whenever I hit the line that reads `Set RAC = CurrentDb...` with:

> Invalid procedure call error

Please let me know if anyone has any idea what produces this error. I've searched everywhere for a possible explanation and I can't find anything that would cause my code to break whenever I try to run a max function. I even made sure that the SalesValue was a Number field in the underlying Access table and that everything was spelled correctly.

Thanks!

Comment: Put a debug breakpoint on that line and copy us the value that RAC gets when the error is thrown.

Comment: I added a watch and the Value for 'RAC' is 'Nothing'.

Comment: Can you run a simple select query using that same function?  Try dropping the terminating semicolon.

Comment: debug.print you SearchString  and paste it into a query sql window and run it. See what happens?

Comment: The part `WHERE [Prefix] = '" & NewPrefix & "';"` is bad. You can get a syntax error in your query that way and get the mentioned error.

Comment: Thanks for your replies! I tried running just the SQL statement in a query window and I got the same error. I'm not sure what is wrong with the syntax though; does that not work for a SQL statement?

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal thank you for your reply. Is it not possible to put a parameter in the where clause of that SQL statement? I've been wracking my brain trying to think of another way to do this, since hardcoding wouldn't work for what I am trying.

Comment: I will add an example, here is the [link to doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa293459(v=vs.60).aspx).

Comment: Or better [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193967.aspx). What is the text of your failing query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the error

> Invalid Procedure Call

on line

```vb
CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SearchString)
```

just because your `SearchString` does not contain a valid SQL query.

Never use string concatenation to pass parameters to a query.
This is bad: `WHERE [Prefix] = 
'" & NewPrefix & "';"`

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10539987/2224701) and parametrize your query.

---

See [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193967.aspx).

First create a query definition:

```vb
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim strSQL As String

Set qdf = dbs.CreateQueryDef("qrySearchQuery")
Application.RefreshDatabaseWindow

strSQL = "PARAMETERS NewPrefix TEXT"
strSQL = strSQL & "SELECT MAX([SalesValue]) FROM [SalesTable] "
strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE [Prefix] = [NewPrefix];"
qdf.SQL = strSQL

qdf.Close
Set qdf = Nothing
```

Then you can call it:

```vb
NewPrefix = Child

Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Set qfd = dbs.QueryDefs("qrySearchQuery")
qdf.Parameters("NewPrefix") = NewPrefix
Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset()
```

Comment: Kudos for properly parameterized SQL. String-concatenated queries are such a plague!

Comment: @Vojtěch Dohnal - thank you very much for your help! If I understand correctly, the parameter described in the documentation and example eliminates the need for concatenating the value directly into the query definition, right? That makes sense; I thought the string concatenation was the approved way of doing this but I guess I was wrong. One quick question about the sample code though - in the line "Set qdf = dbs.CreateQueryDef("qrySearchQuery") is this supposed to be pulling value from something else?

Comment: So when I run it, I trigger an error on the line "Set qdf = dbs.CreateQueryDef("qrySearchQuery"). I'm struggling to understand what this line does; is it necessary to define this up here if you do the same thing below?

Answer (score 0):

You could use *DMax*:

```
Public Function GetMaxValue(Child As String)

    GetMaxValue = DMax("[SalesValue]", "[SalesTable]", "[Prefix] = '" & Child & "'")

End Function
```

Comment: Hi @Gustav - Thank you for your reply. It's the strangest thing, but I tried this approach earlier today and I had the same error that I have now with the SQL. I think it's something with the string concatenation but it was driving me absolutely nuts so I went in another direction with it (SQL instead of DMax) just because I couldn't get it to work no matter how much I tweaked it I don't understand why it doesn't work to be honest though..